# Delete everything from file after reading it

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read the whole file and put it into an array so that I can add more to the array and sort it. Then I want to overwrite the file and add the new array of information. I was used w+ when i open the file but it overwrites it before i can even read the information. So my question is the following. Is there a way that I can read the contents from a file and then after i read everything delete everything from that file? i have the reading from and writing to the file down. It's the deleting everything inside the file I'm having a problem with.

Comment: Why can you not delete the file and recreate it?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)?  I think it is pretty clear about what `w+` does, and what setting would do what you want.

Comment: You describe what you want as three steps: 1, read file; 2, do some stuff with the data, and 3, write back to file. Why not simply perform it in that order. In other words, open the file once for reading, read the data, close the file, do your operations on the data, open the file in write mode, write the data close the file.

Comment: first whatever @JoachimPileborg said or simply delete the file and create a new one

Comment: simply close the file and then reopen it in 'w' mode. This will remove all the contents from the file.

Comment: Read the file, sort, write to a temporary file, delete the original file, rename the temporary file.  All these steps can be recovered after a crash.

Comment: or you can open it rw and use lseek to 0 after the read.  On really low ram systems you can even use this method to do a bubble sort in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to open the file in "read" mode, Scan the data and then do the same in write mode and print the data to the same filename. When you open the filename in writemode you automatically overwrite the old file on the hdd.

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
FILE *inputFile, *outputFile;

// First part - Read from file
inputFile = fopen(INFILENAME, "r"); 
fscanf(inputFile, "Bla Bla Data", &dataFromFile);
fclose(INFILENAME);

// modify the data as needed.

// Second part. - write to same file
outputFile = fopen(OUTFILENAME, "w");
printf("bla bla new data");
fclose(OUTFILENAME);
```